# Text is returning null while parse with retrofit

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2, textview

I am trying to parse a simple json (mentioned below), and setting values to textViews. I am using retrofit and GSON converter. But while setting values to textviw, it is returning me null.
I have already parsed values to recyclerview which is quite easy. But in the simple response i might be making some little mistake but not able to find it.

Help would be appreciated.

### ItemDescriptionInterface

```
public interface ItemDescriptionInterface {
    @GET("getProductDetailByProductId?ProductId=3")
    Call<JsonObject> ITEM_DESCRIPTION_RESPONSE_CALL();
}
```

### Activity

private void GetItemDescription() {

```
    Retrofit retrofit2 = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();


    ItemDescriptionInterface apiService = retrofit2.create(ItemDescriptionInterface.class);
    Call<JsonObject> jsonCall = apiService.ITEM_DESCRIPTION_RESPONSE_CALL();
    jsonCall.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {

            String jsonString = response.body().toString();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            ItemDescriptionModel model = gson.fromJson(jsonString, ItemDescriptionModel.class);
            price.setText(model.getResult().getActualPrice());//Here its not getting 

        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
            String msg = (t.getMessage() == null) ? "Login failed!" : t.getMessage();
            Log.d("descriptionofproduct", msg);
        }
    });
```

JSON response I am getting:

```
{
  "status": "Success",
  "response_code": 200,
  "result": [
    {
      "PId": "3",
      "ProductId": "3",
      "VendorId": "admin",
      "ProductName": "Golden Green",
      "ProductAlias": "golden-green-full-rim-",
      "MarketPrice": "500",
      "ActualPrice": "450",
      "PurchasePrice": "450",
      "Style": "3",
      "DefaultImage_url": "http:\/\/lensclone.tk\/test\.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

### Model

```
public class ItemDescriptionModel {

@SerializedName("ActualPrice")
private String price;

@SerializedName("ProductDetails")
private String productDetails;

@SerializedName("DefaultImage_url")
private String imgurl;

@SerializedName("ProductName")
private String ProductName;

public ItemDescriptionModel(String price, String productDetails, String imgurl, String productName) {
    this.price = price;
    this.productDetails = productDetails;
    this.imgurl = imgurl;
    ProductName = productName;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getProductDetails() {
    return productDetails;
}

public void setProductDetails(String productDetails) {
    this.productDetails = productDetails;
}

public String getImgurl() {
    return imgurl;
}

public void setImgurl(String imgurl) {
    this.imgurl = imgurl;
}

public String getProductName() {
    return ProductName;
}

public void setProductName(String productName) {
    ProductName = productName;
}
```

}

I want to show only actual price.

Let me know if i am missing something.

Comment: Which key is set to get `model.getPrice()`?

Comment: wait let me upload my model class as well

Comment: @buzzingsilently updated.

Comment: Is this the actual response or this is sample?

Comment: actual response....not sample

Comment: share whole `ItemDescriptionModel.class`.

Comment: updated @buzzingsilently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ItemDescriptionInterface**

```
public interface ItemDescriptionInterface {
    @GET("getProductDetailByProductId?ProductId=3")
    Call<ItemDescriptionModel> ITEM_DESCRIPTION_RESPONSE_CALL();
}
```

**Activity**

```
Retrofit retrofit2 = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    ItemDescriptionInterface apiService = retrofit2.create(ItemDescriptionInterface.class);

    Call<ItemDescriptionModel> jsonCall = apiService.ITEM_DESCRIPTION_RESPONSE_CALL();
    jsonCall.enqueue(new Callback<ItemDescriptionModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ItemDescriptionModel> call, Response<ItemDescriptionModel> response) {

            ItemDescriptionModel model = (ItemDescriptionModel) response.body();
            price.setText(model.getResult().get(0).getActualPrice());
        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class ItemDescriptionModel {

@SerializedName("status")
private String status;

@SerializedName("response_code")
private String response_code;

@SerializedName("result")
private List<Results> result;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getResponse_code() {
    return response_code;
}

public void setResponse_code(String response_code) {
    this.response_code = response_code;
}

public List<Results> getResult() {
    return result;
}

public void setResult(List<Results> result) {
    this.result = result;
}

private class Results {

    @SerializedName("PId")
    private String PId;

    @SerializedName("ProductId")
    private String ProductId;

    @SerializedName("VendorId")
    private String VendorId;

    @SerializedName("ProductName")
    private String ProductName;

    @SerializedName("ProductAlias")
    private String ProductAlias;

    @SerializedName("MarketPrice")
    private String MarketPrice;

    @SerializedName("ActualPrice")
    private String ActualPrice;

    @SerializedName("PurchasePrice")
    private String PurchasePrice;

    @SerializedName("Style")
    private String Style;

    @SerializedName("DefaultImage_url")
    private String DefaultImage_url;

    public String getPId() {
        return PId;
    }

    public void setPId(String PId) {
        this.PId = PId;
    }

    public String getProductId() {
        return ProductId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        ProductId = productId;
    }

    public String getVendorId() {
        return VendorId;
    }

    public void setVendorId(String vendorId) {
        VendorId = vendorId;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return ProductName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        ProductName = productName;
    }

    public String getProductAlias() {
        return ProductAlias;
    }

    public void setProductAlias(String productAlias) {
        ProductAlias = productAlias;
    }

    public String getMarketPrice() {
        return MarketPrice;
    }

    public void setMarketPrice(String marketPrice) {
        MarketPrice = marketPrice;
    }

    public String getActualPrice() {
        return ActualPrice;
    }

    public void setActualPrice(String actualPrice) {
        ActualPrice = actualPrice;
    }

    public String getPurchasePrice() {
        return PurchasePrice;
    }

    public void setPurchasePrice(String purchasePrice) {
        PurchasePrice = purchasePrice;
    }

    public String getStyle() {
        return Style;
    }

    public void setStyle(String style) {
        Style = style;
    }

    public String getDefaultImage_url() {
        return DefaultImage_url;
    }

    public void setDefaultImage_url(String defaultImage_url) {
        DefaultImage_url = defaultImage_url;
    }
}}
```

Comment: what code should i change in activity ?? can u please suggest me.??

Comment: its shoing error on   price.setText(model.getResult()); .... also.. its not accesing getActualPrice. Should i share code again??

Comment: Please correct me if i am wrong, is Result class should public?

Comment: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 52 path $.result

Comment: this is the log i am getting

Comment: Result has list of elements, I have updated model & activity code.please check

Comment: dear life saver @buzzing thanks a ton. I dont have words to express my happiness. Stuck here for almost 6 hour, and my friend suggested me to go for SO. Billions of thanks to you dude.

Comment: Please up-vote this answer, If helped. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have received a valid response successfully, you are not parsing the json correctly. The `model` object does not contain the `ActualPrice`, this has to be parsed further from the obtained json.

You would need to create model classes for the response object (ItemDescriptionModel) as well as any nested objects within the response json, like `result` here. You can also use online tools like [JsontoJava](http://json2java.azurewebsites.net/), etc. that can generate the model class required.

Once the model class is created as required,

Replace

```
price.setText(model.getPrice());
```

with

```
price.setText(model.getResult().getPrice());
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this things.

```
public interface ItemDescriptionInterface {
    @GET("getProductDetailByProductId?ProductId=3")
    Call<ItemDescriptionModel> ITEM_DESCRIPTION_RESPONSE_CALL();
}
        Call<ItemDescriptionModel> itemDescriptionModelCall= apiService.ITEM_DESCRIPTION_RESPONSE_CALL();
    itemDescriptionModelCall.enqueue(new Callback<ItemDescriptionModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ItemDescriptionModel> call, retrofit2.Response<ItemDescriptionModel> response) {
            if (response!=null && response.isSuccessful() && response.body()!=null){
                String prince=response.body().getPrice();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ItemDescriptionModel> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: i things your json format has some error. put this site in your json code it give all java class ..http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/